# When is a device token assigned?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying the Urban Airship APNS development push server. When I run their sample app, I can't seem to get the Device Token. What needs to be done to make sure the token exists?
I've checked the provisioning profile and the bundle id.

Does my server need to push (through UrbanAirship) for the token to be generated for the first time?  Is the token generated at the first push time? How do I register devices to receive push notifications? (I assume that this is built into the sample app, but what do I know...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The token is generated when you call -registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:. Assuming this call is successful, the token is generated and returned via callback. If you've properly uploaded your APNS certificate to Urban Airship, and created the proper mobileprovision file (and, of course, built against it), that's all that's required.

Comment: `...uploaded your APNS certificate to Urban Airship...` the p12, right?

Comment: Yep, that's the one. You can check its status on the UA site.

Comment: Worked the second time. Not sure why... I've got another peros pushing to me. I'm the app guy, he's configuring the UA account and server....